# Como intercambiar un valor del mismo atributo entre dos instancias de una clase?

Tags: django, django-models, aplicación-web

Siguiendo con un proyecto de un torneo de tenis.
Luego de realizar un partido, dependiendo el resultado necesito que los jugadores (instancia de clase Jugador) intercambie posicion en una tabla con otro jugador.

El problema es que no puedo tener dos jugadores asignados por "mala intencion" ni por accidente en la misma posicion, por lo que el atributo es "posicion = models.CharField(unique=True)" creo que el conflicto esta a la hora de la reasignacion adjunto models.py y views.py donde estan las funciones en cuestion. Desde ya muchas gracias por algun posible feedback.

**models.py**

```
class Jugador(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False,blank=False)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    posicion = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    pj = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pg = models.IntegerField(default=0)  
    pp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desafiado = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural =  'jugadores'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    



class Desafio(models.Model):
    atacante = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    defensor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    at1set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    de1set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    at2set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    de2set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    attb = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    detb = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    pendiente = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Desafio entre {self.atacante} y {self.defensor}'
```

**views.py**

```
def update_desafio(request, des_id):
    """editar un desafio pendiente"""
    desafio= Desafio.objects.get(id=des_id)
    mij=Jugador.objects.get(user=request.user)
    retrieve_def = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=desafio.defensor)
    stakes= [mij.posicion,retrieve_def.posicion]
    stakes.sort()
        
    #chequeo 
    if desafio.atacante != mij.nombre and desafio.defensor != mij.nombre:
        return render(request,'escalerilla/deny.html')

    elif request.method != ('POST'):
        #visualizar la info actual del desafio
        form = DesafioForm(instance=desafio)
    else:
        # POST agregar informacion del desafio
        form = DesafioForm(instance=desafio, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        
        
            obj = form.save(commit = False) 
            obj.pendiente = False
            obj.save() 
            
            #posiciones en juego
            

            #Identificar ganador y perdedor
            jug_ganador=definir_ganador(obj)
            jug_perdedor=definir_perdedor(obj,jug_ganador)
                        
            #retrieve la instancia 
            perdedor = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=jug_perdedor)
            ganador = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=jug_ganador)
            
            #actualizar datos de los jugadores
            
            ganador.pg += 1
            ganador.pj += 1
            perdedor.pp += 1
            perdedor.pj += 1
            ganador.posicion = stakes[0]
            perdedor.posicion = stakes[1]
            ganador.desafiado = False
            perdedor.desafiado = False
            ganador.save()
            perdedor.save()
           

            return redirect('escalerilla:mi_ficha')
    
    context = {'desafio': desafio, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'escalerilla/update.html', context)
```

traceback.py

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/34/

Django Version: 4.0.4
Python Version: 3.10.4
Installed Applications:
['users',
 'escalerilla',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: escalerilla_jugador.posicion) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\Documents\Programming\Python\tennis2\escalerilla\views.py", line 157, in update_desafio
    ganador.save()
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 970, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1034, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 885, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1783, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /update/34/
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: escalerilla_jugador.posicion
```

Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Por si le interesa a alguien. Resolvi el problema generando una posicion temporal en el bloque "if" con un valor que nunca podria pertenecer a ningun jugador (ej: posicion = 10000).